# Transition from @HeadlessUI not working properly in React + Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, headless-ui

i´m having an issue when trying to use the @headlessUI transition. I´m applying it exactly as the documentation says, and the transition duration works, but not the change in opacity. Here´s the piece of code:

```
const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false)

return (
  <div className="bg-gray-800">
    <>
      <FaShoppingCart className="h-7 w-7 absolute top-10 right-10 z-50 text-white cursor- 
      pointer" onClick={() => {
        setIsShowing((isShowing) => !isShowing)}} />
      <Transition
        appear={true}
        show={isShowing}
        enter="transition-opacity duration-75"
        enterFrom="opacity-0"
        enterTo="opacity-100"
        leave="transition-opacity duration-150"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100"
        leaveTo="opacity-0"
      >
        <Cart />
      </Transition>
    </>
```

the Transition is correctly imported, @headlessUI is installed. To check, i´ve changed the duration to 500, and all it does is to take 500ms to show up, but with no transition (and the duration only works at the fade in, not at the fade out)